# Python non-greedy regex match with pattern in between

Tags: python, regex

OK, I know this is a very common question. I've searched and searched but couldn't find anything that solved my problem.

So I have some text:

> #u'15" approx. length from waist to hem, 26" waist#Measured from
>   Small#Shell: 100% Polyester, Lining: 100% Polyester#Machine wash cold,
>   tumble dry low#Imported'

These are basically lines separated by `#`. I would like to get the line containing `%` which would be:

`#Shell: 100% Polyester, Lining: 100% Polyester#`.

So I try and search for this pattern:

`#.*%.*#`

but this wasn't greedy so I tried:

`#.*?%.*?#`

After this I am getting:

`#u'15" approx. length from waist to hem, 26" waist#Measured from Small#Shell: 100% Polyester, Lining: 100% Polyester#`

Still not greedy from the beginning. What am I missing?

Comment: What about: `Measured from Small`

Comment: Why should a line between `#` and `#` containing `%` should return `#Machine wash cold, tumble dry low#` ??

Comment: @Anubhava It was a mistake. Thanks for pointing it our. I've corrected it.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I don't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: Then your [regex should work](https://regex101.com/r/rH9hO2/1)

Comment: It works on the site you've mentioned but not in my python console. I'm trying `re.search(r'#.*?%.*?#', line).group()` and it's still returning the result I mentioned earlier

Comment: @anubhava I tried that and it's still giving the same output.

Comment: @anubhava The expression given in the answer by geckon works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want the lines containing `%` you can do something like this:

```
text = '15" approx. length from waist to hem, 26" waist#Measured from Small#Shell: 100% Polyester, Lining: 100% Polyester#Machine wash cold, tumble dry low#Imported'
for line in text.split('#'):
    if '%' in line:
        # it's the line, do something
```

You can also use list comprehension:

```
text = '15" approx. length from waist to hem, 26" waist#Measured from Small#Shell: 100% Polyester, Lining: 100% Polyester#Machine wash cold, tumble dry low#Imported'
matches = [line for line in text.split('#') if '%' in line]
```

If you really want to use a regular expression, you can do this:

```
import re

text = '15" approx. length from waist to hem, 26" waist#Measured from Small#Shell: 100% Polyester, Lining: 100% Polyester#Machine wash cold, tumble dry low#Imported'
line_re = re.compile('#[^#]*%[^#]*#')
matches = line_re.findall(text)
```

To explain the regular expression used:

```
'#[^#]*%[^#]*#'
```

We're looking for something starting with a `#`, then with `[^#]*` we want to greedily match as many characters that are not `#` as possible (`[^#]` means any character different from `#`, `*` means repetition), then we want to match a `%`, then `[^#]*` again and the whole match should end with a `#`.

Comment: Yes that is the work around I've been using. But I started out with regex and not being able to make it work is stuck in my head. Is there any way to do it using regex?

Comment: @PraveshJain While it's fair enough to ask out of interest how to do it with a regular expression (and I'm sure you will get an answer), I agree that this is the much better way of doing what you want. Simple is best.

Comment: As an extension to this - if you want a list, this is a good case for a list comprehension `[line for line in text.split('#') if '%' in line]`.

Comment: @Lattyware Totally agree with you. But I wanted to get it out of my head so bad.

Comment: @geckon Your regex works. Could you explain it a little bit? 
Thanks

Comment: @PraveshJain I can understand that - it's a perfectly valid question on SO,  just worth making the comment again so if someone comes along they don't think it's the solution they should use.

Comment: @PraveshJain Do you understand it with the added explanation?

Answer (score 1):

You can precede your non-greedy match (`.*?`) with a greedy match (`.*`).

```
import re
s = u'15" approx. length from waist to hem, 26" waist#Measured from Small#Shell: 100% Polyester, Lining: 100% Polyester#Machine wash cold, tumble dry low#Imported'

print re.findall(".*#(.*?%.*?)#", s)[0]
print re.search(".*#(.*?%.*?)#", s).groups()[0]
```

Comment: Your expression works with re.findall but not with re.search. I can't understand why.